# Are Norse flytings the spiritual forebearer of the modern rap battle?

Tags: norse

A [flyting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyting) has been defined as:

> "a contest consisting of the exchange of insults, often conducted in verse, between two parties."
>
> <sub>Source: Parks, Ward. "Flyting, Sounding, Debate: Three Verbal Contest Genres", Poetics Today 7.3, Poetics of Fiction (1986:439-458)</sub>

So are flytings the forebearer of [Rap Battles](https://youtu.be/ylkOAtifuJ0), such as the one depicted in the film 8 Mile between Eminem and Papa Doc?  Are there other cultures where a poetic battle of wits played a central role in the mythos, such as with the [Loksenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lokasenna)?

Comment: Troubadours had the [*tenso*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenso): it wasn't necessarily insults but was definitely a debate/an exchange, in verse, between two poets.

Comment: What's a "spiritual forebearer"? Trading insults via verse has long preceded the Norse.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer take it to mean "in the spirit of".  What are some of the pre-Norse precedents?

Answer (score 3):

**Not exactly**

Flyting could be more closely related to "roasting" your friend. A man was measured by his intelligence. Whether he traveled and whether he could tell great tales of his travels. That is what a man was measured by. If he never left home he was "unlearned" and was a "simple" person. A good example of this is the Icelandic word Heimskur heim-skur ( home-ish ) was originally used for people that have never seen anything except how things are at home. It was not used over people that are not bright. Now in a modern sense the meaning has changed to mean "stupid". This culture still believes that a home-body was a dumb uneducated person.
Flyting was considered a game and in good jest. But the men exchanging would really insult one another. Rap battles aren't usually in good spirits, at least not in 8-mile they weren't. Flyting is a battle of wits. There wasn't always music involved. It was the mental equivalent to an arm wrestling contest.

Modern men do this in order to toughen each other up, both physically and emotionally. Because, if you can't take some good-natured ego jabs from your boy, how can you stand up to your true enemies? I'm sure the context hasn't really changed much!

And in closing I'll leave you with this adage:

"Men socialise by insulting each other, but don't really mean it. While women socialise by complimenting each other, but don't really mean it"

Comment: That is some good context.  I was recently referred to this very compelling paper by John McKinnel "[Motivation in Lokasenna](http://www.vsnrweb-publications.org.uk/Saga-Book%20XXII.pdf)" where he makes the point that "most verbal battles are not motiveless, but have some practical intention and result", listing the Vafþrúðnismál, Alvíssmál, among others, and the Hárbarðsljóð, which is a flyting between Thor and Halbard the Ferryman.

Comment: @DukeZhou Exactly. Most of these instances of flyting occur in the context of great men. In Lokasenna Halbard rips into Thor by suggesting that Sif is a whore, but Thor never counters it, leaving us to understand that he was accepting of her promiscuity. It should also be noted that Halbard in that story is actually Odin in disguise.

Comment: which goes a long way to explaining why it's conclusion is not fatal (as in most battle of wits with the Allfather ;)